# Multiple parallels api call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga and redux libraries to handle my project in React.

I'll explain my issue: in one moment the frontend application will dispatch n multiple identical saga "CUSTOM_ACTION" action (expected behaviour). Now I'd like to have only one api calls even the actions are multiple. Take latest option doesn't work.

This my saga code:

`function* testWorker() {`

   `// call api only once`

`}`


`function* testWatcher() {`

  `yield takeLatest("CUSTOM_ACTION", testWorker);`

`}`

With this configuration I have n api calls, one for each action.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance to everyone who can help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [link] https://codesandbox.io/s/test-concurrency-forked-yu7lxz here a short example

Answer (score 0):

The answer kind of depends on what you mean by "in one moment".

If you mean that only one request should be running at a time, you can use the `takeLeading` effect instead of `takeLatest`. It will start the request for the first action dispatched an ignore all the others until the request saga is finished.

```js
function* testWatcher() {
  yield takeLeading("CUSTOM_ACTION", testWorker);
}
```

If you mean some specific time, you can use the `debounce` effect. It will run only a single saga for a given time (once the time is over, with the last action dispatched).

```js
function* testWatcher() {
  yield debounce(500, "CUSTOM_ACTION", testWorker);
}
```

You can run it with `0` for a very short amount of time.

There is also the `throttle` effect if you just want to limit the amount of requests created.

Comment: I mean that if I'll receive n identical actions (in this case "CUSTOM ACTION") only one further action will be dispatched (even if n multiple CUSTOM ACTION" have a little delay). I want to realize a sort of collector (n identical input -> only 1 output) takeLeading doesn't work for my scope

Comment: In that case the `debounce` effect should work, the number will be the amount of ms that you still consider "little delay"

Comment: Thanks Martin you solved my problem! Thanks thanks thanks